# Jordan basis of the matrix with the only one eigenvalue 0

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Find the Jordan basis of the following matrix: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& -2& 3& -1\\
0 & 0 &-1 &2 &0\\
2& 2& -6& 10& -2\\
1& 1& -3& 5&  -1\\
 0& 0& 0& 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$$

The only eigenvalue of this matrix is zero, so the rank is equal to 1 . So how could I get the Jordan basis, if I am not able to get it classicaly from the chaining of the eigenvectors (Jordan's chain)?

Comment: Your claim is a non-sequitur. The zero matrix also has only $0$ as an eigenvalue, but its rank is zero. In fact, the rank of this matrix is greater than one.

Comment: Regardless, why would the rank being one prevent the “classical” method from working?

Comment: the rank is 2. The characteristic polynomial is $x^5,$ but the minimal polynomial is $x^2.$ This means you get a single 1 by 1 block and two 2 by2 blocks in the Jordan form.

Comment: I was very confused and didnt understand it, so thank you for your responses.